# ArrayList.add() ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException processing

Tags: java

He buscado en esta página pero no encuentro una solución. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
class BodyThread extends Thread {
private Thread t;
private String threadName;
private boolean isCreature;
ArrayList<Creature> creatures;
ArrayList<DeadBody> bodies;
double timeStep;

public BodyThread(String name, ArrayList array, double ts, boolean ic/*, Boolean uc*/) {
  threadName = name;
  timeStep = ts;
  isCreature = ic;
  if(ic) creatures = array;
  else bodies = array;
}
public void run() {
  if(isCreature){
    for(int i = 0; i<creatures.size(); i++){
      creatures.get(i).collide(timeStep);
      creatures.get(i).metabolize(timeStep);
      creatures.get(i).useBrain(timeStep/*, !userControl*/);
      if(creatures.get(i).getRadius() < creatures.get(i).board.MINIMUM_SURVIVABLE_SIZE){
        creatures.get(i).returnToEarth();
        creatures.remove(creatures.get(i));
        i--;
        return;
      }       
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<creatures.size(); i++){
      Creature cr = creatures.get(i);
     creatures.get(i).applyMotions(timeStep*cr.board.OBJECT_TIMESTEPS_PER_YEAR);
     creatures.get(i).see(timeStep*cr.board.OBJECT_TIMESTEPS_PER_YEAR);
    }   
  }else{
    for(int i = 0; i<bodies.size(); i++){
      bodies.get(i).collide(timeStep);
      bodies.get(i).decay(timeStep);
      if(bodies.get(i).getRadius() <= 0){
        bodies.remove(bodies.get(i));
        i--;
        return;
      }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<bodies.size(); i++) bodies.get(i).applyMotions(timeStep*bodies.get(i).board.OBJECT_TIMESTEPS_PER_YEAR);
  }  
}

public void start () {
  if (t == null) {
     t = new Thread (this, threadName);
     t.start ();
    }
  }
}
class SoftBody{
double px;
double py;
double vx;
double vy;
double energy;
float ENERGY_DENSITY; 
double density;
double hue;
double saturation;
double brightness;
double birthTime;
boolean isCreature = false;
final float FRICTION = 0.004;
final float COLLISION_FORCE = 0.01;
final float FIGHT_RANGE = 2.0;
double fightLevel = 0;
ArrayList<SoftBody> colliders;
Board board;

public void collide(double timeStep){
  colliders = new ArrayList<SoftBody>(0);
  for(int x = SBIPMinX; x <= SBIPMaxX; x++){
    for(int y = SBIPMinY; y <= SBIPMaxY; y++){
      for(int i = 0; i < board.softBodiesInPositions[x][y].size(); i++){
        SoftBody newCollider = (SoftBody)board.softBodiesInPositions[x][y].get(i);
        if(!colliders.contains(newCollider) && newCollider != this){
          colliders.add(newCollider); //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < colliders.size(); i++){
    SoftBody collider = colliders.get(i);
    float distance = dist((float)px,(float)py,(float)collider.px,(float)collider.py);
    double combinedRadius = getRadius()+collider.getRadius();
    if(distance < combinedRadius){
      double force = combinedRadius*COLLISION_FORCE;
      vx += ((px-collider.px)/distance)*force/getMass();
      vy += ((py-collider.py)/distance)*force/getMass();
    }
  }
  fightLevel = 0;
}
}
class Board{
  void iterate(){// I'll just put the part where I run the thread.
    creaturesThread = new BodyThread("Creature Thread", creatures, timeStep, true);
    bodiesThread = new BodyThread("Bodies Thread", bodies, timeStep, false);
    creaturesThread.start();
    bodiesThread.start();
    try{
      creaturesThread.join();
      bodiesThread.join();
    }catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

(Esta es solo la parte importante de el código).
Por lo que se, la función get no debería dar error. Me gustaría saber que puedo hacer para que esto no pase. Gracias.

Comment: La pregunta la puedes poner en español por favor.

Comment: @DarthVader ya está. Creía que estaba en la versión en inglés.

Comment: Por favor incluye el los detalles completos del error (mensaje + stack trace). Además, es necesario que nos des un [mcve].

Comment: No creo que el error se lance en esa línea. Por favor muestra el stacktrace. La excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` significa que has accedido a una posición que no existe en un arreglo, no en una lista. `List#add` solo puede lanzar dicha excepción si es que este código se ejecuta en un ambiente multi thread. De ser eso cierto, necesitamos ver cómo se ejecuta este código, porque tal como lo presentas no se levantará ese problema.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza efectivamente tengo multiThreading. Ya he añadido el código. Pero a lo que a mi respecta, el thread está bien hecho. Y como utilizo processing, no me sale es stacktrace.

Comment: Cambia la definición de tu variable que usarás para almacenar los elementos de manera concurrente de `ArrayList` a una clase que sí soporte multi thread como `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (muy lento en performance) o a una implementación de [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) como `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: puede que tu problema este en la condicion del ciclo for ahi donde dice:x <= SBIPMaxX tambien abajo y <= SBIPMaxY creo que debe ser solo menor no (menor o igual).   de todas formas seria bueno que proporciones la pila de errores que te sale.

Comment: En mi opinión, el código aún no es un [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Lo más probable es que tu problema es una condición de carrera, a causa que accedes a una lista con hebras que no esta sincronizada (no segura en hebras / not thread safe).

Internamente el método `ArrayList#add(Object o)` mide el tamaño de la lista y luego agrega el elemento en la posición `size()` (que es el ultimo indice más uno).

Si entre medir el tamaño actual y agregar el elemento pasa una reducción de tamaño por `remove`, se causa una excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`.

Una solución para tu problema puede ser de sincronizar el código en que agregas y remueves objetos de la lista, o usas una `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, para evitar este problema.

Probablemente la manera más fácil (no necesariamente lo mejor) es sincronizar los `ArrayList` usando `Collections`:

```
List<Creatures> creatures = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Creatures>());
```

Answer (score -2):

En este caso esta definido correctamente el ArrayList:

```
 colliders = new ArrayList<SoftBody>(0);
```

El error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` puede suceder al agregar un elemento a tu `ArrayList` que en algún momento  `newCollider` tiene valor null:

```
 colliders.add(newCollider);
```

Te lo explico con esta imagen, si agregas a tu `ArrayList` un elemento con valor `null`,  este ejemplo el 8 (indice 7), la medida de tu ArrayList es la de los elementos que agregaste pero en realidad solo puedes consultar 9 ya que uno contiene un valor null.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

otra causa puede ser que tu ArrayList este siendo modificado por otro Thread.

Comment: Disculpa ser el molestoso nuevamente, pero no veo como esto explica el `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Agregar un `null` a un `ArrayList` es perfectamente válido, y si no lo fuera, resultaría en un `NullPointerException` si acaso. Yo pienso mas bien que OP está malintepretando el lugar donde sucede el error.

Comment: @sstan eso o el código se ejecuta en un ambiente multi thread y esta lista es modificada al "mismo tiempo" por dos o más hilos.

Comment: @Luiggi: Eso sí que es posible :)

Comment: @sstan **Nunca he dicho que agregar un valor null a un ArrayList no es válido**  y que agregar el null  provoca ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. El error puede ser incluso aquí :  board.softBodiesInPositions[x][y].size()

Comment: Copiado textualmente de tu respuesta: "El error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` puede suceder al agregar un elemento a tu `ArrayList` que en algún momento `newCollider` tiene valor null". Si `newCollider` es el elemento que se está agregando y dices que si tiene valor null puede causar este efecto, eso significa que "agregar un valor null a un ArrayList es la causa del problema.